# Get result (errorCount, failureCount...) of JUnitTest

Tags: java, ant, junit

I figured out how to use the Ant API to run a JUnit Test and create an XML of the result.

```
String pathToReports = "/tmp/junitreports";
Project project = new Project();
JUnitTest test = null;

try 
{
    new File(pathToReports).mkdir();
    JUnitTask task = new JUnitTask();

    project.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir",pathToReports);
    task.setProject(project);

    FormatterElement.TypeAttribute type = new FormatterElement.TypeAttribute();
    type.setValue("xml");

    FormatterElement formater = new FormatterElement();   
    formater.setType(type);
    task.addFormatter(formater);

    test = new JUnitTest(TestClass.class.getName());
    test.setTodir(new File(pathToReports));
    task.addTest(test); 
    task.execute();

} 
...
```

TestClass:

```
public class TestClass
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        fail("failed");
    }
}
```

The Code works just fine. The XML is created and I can see that the test "failed".

Now my question: is there any way to also get the test results programatically? I expected to get an updated version of the JUnitTest object somehow where I can call the method "failureCount()".

test.failurecount() after execution of the task returns 0 of course. Parsing the XML seems odd to me as the number of failures should already be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable (`int failedTests`) increment each time a test fails. You could do this by using a [TestWatcher](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) rule.

After all the tests have run you could print it out (or do whatever you wanna do with it...) with:

```
@AfterClass
public static void printFailedTestsCount() {
    System.out.println(failedTests + " tests failed.");
}
```